# Wordpress does not output "post" class when calling post_class() function

Tags: posts

I am writing an ajax call to a server which requests a next set of posts. However when I try to generate a list of posts I am having an issue with post_class() function. It does not add a "post" class to post.

```
$osetin_query = new WP_Query( $args );
while ($osetin_query->have_posts()) : $osetin_query->the_post(); ?>
  <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>></article>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Result:

```
<article id="post-154" class="post-154 type-post">
```

Expected result:

```
<article id="post-154" class="post-154 post type-post">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`get_post_class()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_class) generates and returns the list of classes echoed by [`post_class()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/post_class). The only reason for the function itself not producing the result you want can be found in the source [`post-template.php`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.9.1/src/wp-includes/post-template.php#L401):

```
        if ( ! is_admin() )  
                $classes[] = $post->post_type;
```

Which means that the class `post` actually only gets generated if [`is_admin()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_admin) *doesn't* apply.

Another possibility actually could be that the filter [post_class](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.9.1/src/wp-includes/post-template.php#L466) is used to prevent the class. But given the available information this can just be a non-grounded assumption.

Comment: So if I am using  **wp_ajax_** and **wp_ajax_nopriv_** hooks  in **functions.php** and to load extra posts I am always going to hit "**is_admin()**" condition? Is there a workaround?

Comment: I don't think `is_admin` should be true for `wp_ajax_nopriv_ `